# Assembly 8086: DES encryption binary shifts

Tags: assembly, encryption, bit-shift, des, emu8086

so I working on DES encryption program in assembly 8086 and I got to the part when I have to do the permuted key-k+, split it and then do some shift every iteration.
The problem  is every half of k+ is 28 bits so I can't put the in a var and do "shl". How can I solve it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

`RCL r/m, 1` or `RCR r/m, 1` are the instructions to shift several combined registers/variables:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK

.DATA
    k dd 12345678h      ; 00010010 00110100 01010110 01111000

.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, k + 0
    mov dx, k + 2

    shl ax, 1           ; Shift out leftmost bit into Carry, shift in 0
    rcl dx, 1           ; Shift in Carry

    mov k + 0, ax       ; 00100100 01101000 10101100 11110000
    mov k + 2, dx


    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: On real Intel CPUs, `adc dx,dx` is a more efficient way to shift in the previous CF.  Single uop on Broadwell and later (or 2 uops in Haswell and earlier) because it writes all FLAGS as output, unlike RCL (3 uops even on Skylake) which leaves some unmodified.  For right shifts you do want RCR though.  (Or SHRD on 386+).

Answer (score 2):

What I'm doing is getting to the last byte of the key and I'm using RCL. Then I'm doing it on the byte before, until I get to the first byte. What I am doing is using RCL as normal but then I'm JC and if the carry flag equals 1, use the OR operation on the last byte of the key and turn on the right bit.

[image]

EDIT: the arrow is pointing to the wrong bit, it should point to the rightest bit.